# Leaderboard with unique teams

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a leaderboard that requires the sorting of team scores uniquely. So far I have written a query that will sort the teams score however I am not sure how to write it so that it will eliminate duplicates where two entries have the same players.

My table structure is as follows:

- match_data: Contains information about the type of match (time played, mode, etc)
- player_data: Contains the player data for a match (including score) as well as foreign keys for the matchID and playerID

My current query which will sort the match entries based on score of the players that left join. (All players in the match will have the same score, a team can consist of 4 players or less):

```
SELECT id
FROM match_data md
  LEFT JOIN player_data pd ON pd.matchID = md.matchID
WHERE version = '1.4'
  AND mode = 3
ORDER by pd.score DESC
```

Results for this query would look like (with additional data selects):

```
id | playerid | score
---------------------
 0    1 2 3 4    10    
 4    1 3 4 5     9
 8    6 8 1 2     8
 3    3 2 4 1     7
 7    9 2 3 2     3
```

Sample query of one match (match_data col 1-4, player_data col 5-8):

```
id      matchID version mode    id      matchID steamID     score 
40437   4853226 1.4     3       83955   4853226 119907712   98968 
40437   4853226 1.4     3       83953   4853226 111380990   98968 
40437   4853226 1.4     3       83954   4853226 111227926   98968 
40437   4853226 1.4     3       83957   4853226 66998815    98968
```

However I would like it to look like the results below (without id 3 since it is a duplicate of the id 0 having the same players):

```
id | playerid | score
---------------------
 0    1 2 3 4    10    
 4    1 3 4 5     9
 8    6 8 1 2     8
 7    9 2 3 2     3
```

Comment: Do you store 4 player_id's in the same column?

Comment: if you can recreate your tables: Teams, Players, Matches. much better to link data on unique ID's than PlayerID's mashed together with no real team identifier.

Comment: ID 0 and 3 are duplicates because the have the same players, got it.  How did you conclude that 3 is the duplicate and not 0? Was it the most recent match or is that a parameter specified by the user calling this query?

Comment: Player ids or player_data foreign keys are not stored on the match_data table and must be searched for. I went this way as it is the easiest to build a database where match players can be anywhere from 1 to 8 players. Sorting by unique match (or 'team') is a new feature that is in progress so I have not planned ahead when creating the database. It will not be hard however to add foreign keys for each player if required.

Comment: @Jeff the only duplicate kept should be the one with the highest score.

Matt since the 'teams' are only dependant on who played the match, creating an identify for the 'team' on the fly might be a viable option instead of a table.

Comment: So, it's Match 1 Players Many. You want to return the match containing the unique set of players with the highest score yes?

Comment: That is correct, and then order the matches of all the unique sets of players based on score.

Comment: OK, one last question - how is it that your query is returning 1 row for matches with 4 players - it seems like if this is a 1:many query (assuming 4 players per match) it would return 4 rows for each match... are you using a list_agg (oracle - I forgot the mysql equivalent) function of some sort?

Comment: That query at the moment would not return all 4 players. It would only return the first matching player it finds, which is all I need when sorting by score with duplicates as all the players contain the same score data in the same match.

Comment: It looks as though in its current state it would return 4 records. Can you run it and show us some actual sample output please with all the columns you're selecting included?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, it will in fact return all player records for each match.

Comment: id matchID version mode id matchID steamID score
40437 4853226 1.4 3 83955 4853226 119907712 98968
40437 4853226 1.4 3 83953 4853226 111380990 98968
40437 4853226 1.4 3 83954 4853226 111227926 98968
40437 4853226 1.4 3 83957 4853226 66998815 98968

Sample data (first 4 columns belong to match_data where the player_data left join begins after) 


Haste bin of data displayed correctly http://hastebin.com/avizolibit.md

Comment: I think it best if you show your table structure in your original question and along with this sample output. I'll have a look again soon - off to work...